# How to add custom text elements in Limesurvey?

Tags: templates, localization, translation, limesurvey

By default, Limesurvey provides the follow text elements for the surveys - Survey title, Description, Welcome message, End message etc, which I can use in my template with tags like `{SURVEYNAME}`, `{SURVEYDESCRIPTION}`, `{WELCOME}` etc.

Is it possible to add my own custom field, which I can then use in the template? I need to do it this way because I need to have the text translatable, and present on every page.

Comment: No, not actually, plugin can do this : but need more explanation why you don't use SURVEYDESCRIPTION for your purpose.

Comment: I need to add some text next to the language select dropdown to say "please choose your language" in different language, so it's not part of the description. The description field is used already

Comment: You already have this sentence but with hide class. Try , at end of you template.css file: `.hide.label{display:inline-block;position:relative;top:auto;left:auto}` can be template dependent.

Comment: @DenisChenu I tried that but nothing changed, and I cannot find this text next to the language changer. The entire `.lang-wrapper` is the following

Comment: `<div class="lang-wrapper"><select id="languagechanger" name="languagechanger" class="languagechanger" onchange="javascript:window.location=this.value">
<option value="/index.php/385116/lang-ar">عَرَبيْ</option>
<option value="/index.php/385116/lang-en" selected="selected">English</option>
<option value="/index.php/385116/lang-pt">Português</option>
<option value="/index.php/385116/lang-es">Español</option>
</select>
</div>`

Comment: I don't want to show the label for the fields / text elements. I want some ***custom*** text next to the language selector

Comment: You use an old LimeSurvey version ... the you need use javascript. Put the solution at answer in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not add a custom replacement with the current version of LimeSurvey. And your LimeSurvey version seems outdated. But LS includes jquery, therefore it's easy to move some element from a place to elsewhere.

Quick example:

```
<p>Here is your description</p>
<div style='display:none'>
<label for='languagechanger' id='labellang'>Here is the new label for language</label>
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#labellang").insertAfter("#languagechanger")
});
</script>
```

A PHP solution, hacking LimeSurvey code, should be placed at https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/blob/master/application/helpers/replacements_helper.php#L814

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, but the real problem is I need the label to be translatable, and I need a place in the admin panel where the user can update it, just like the other text elements.

Comment: But : here : label is in description, then it's translatable. If you need another solution : hack the PHP code.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for letting me know that this is the only solution.

Comment: Hacking LimeSurvey to add your own 'replacement' can be done here https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/blob/master/application/helpers/replacements_helper.php#L814